# Cron job use for running hadoop program in linux

Tags: linux, hadoop, cron

I am new two linux and for my project we are using hadoop.Now we have written 3 mapreduce program in such a way output of 1st program is input to the 2nd program and the output of 2nd program is input to the third.But we are running the 3 different conf means first we are running configuration of 1st program and then 2nd and after that 3rd.Now we want two run all the 3 program one after the other is it possible using cron job in linux if yes please mention the steps.We want two use cron job because we need two run 3-programs repeatively for several hours

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Create a shell script by using **&&** to execute your hadoop programs sequentially. Execute your first command and then use `&&` then your second command and so on.

Ex: `first command && second command && third command`

**2.** Type this in terminal:

```
crontab -e
```

This will open cronjob editor in terminal.

Add this line to run your shell script every 15 mins,

```
*/15 * * * * /path/to/your/shell/script
```

For more help about crontab, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

**DELETE/COPY OUTPUT DIRECTORY:**

If you want to avoid directory already exists error, delete or copy the output directory before executing your hadoop sequential jobs. Add this in your shell script before hadoop job commands:

```
# Delete the output directory in HDFS
hadoop fs -rmr /your/hdfs/output/directory/to/be/deleted
# Copy the output directory from HDFS to HDFS
hadoop fs -mkdir /new/hdfs/location
hadoop fs -cp /your/hdfs/output/directory/to/be/copied/*.* /new/hdfs/location
# Copy from HDFS to local filesystem
sudo mkdir /path/to/local/filesystem
hadoop fs -copyToLocal /your/hdfs/output/directory/to/be/copied/*.* /path/to/local/filesystem
```

> **NOTE:** If you are using latest hadoop version, replace **hadoop fs** with **hdfs dfs** and **-rmr** with **-rm -r**. Dont forget to add **"*.*"** when copying a directory since this will copy all contents of that directory. Change the HDFS file paths as per your configuration.

Comment: i m facing problem with executing hadoop program sequentially the question is after  excuting complete script i hv two also write script for deleting the output ?

Comment: Cant understand what you are trying to tell.. Please explain your problem clearly.

Comment: once i run the script and all the 3 programs have run successfully but as it is the cron job it will run again and again after few intervals so i need two write the script to delete the output which is generated by the program previously if i did not delete the output it will throw an error.

Comment: Updated answer. Check it out. If it helps, mark this as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

the best way for handling this case is with chain mapreduce approach.

http://gandhigeet.blogspot.in/2012/12/as-discussed-in-previous-post-hadoop.html

i am posting driver code for calling three mapreduce jobs..

```
 public class ExerciseDriver {


static Configuration conf;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ExerciseDriver ED = new ExerciseDriver();
    conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);

    if(args.length < 2) {
        System.out.println("Too few arguments. Arguments should be:  <hdfs input folder> <hdfs output folder> ");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    String pathin1 = args[0];
    String pathout1 = args[1];


     //Run first Map reduce job
    fs.delete(new Path(pathout1+"_1"), true);

    ED.runFirstJob(pathin1, pathout1+"_1");

    ED.runSecondJob(pathout1+"_1", pathout1+"_2");

    ED.runThirdJob(pathout1+"_2", pathout1+"3");


}

  public int runFirstJob(String pathin, String pathout) throws Exception {

    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJarByClass(ExerciseDriver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(ExerciseMapper1.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(ExerciseCombiner.class);
    job.setReducerClass(ExerciseReducer1.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(ParagrapghInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class); 
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(pathin));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(pathout));

   job.submit();  

   job.getMaxMapAttempts();


    boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    return success ? 0 : -1;

}

  public int runSecondJob(String pathin, String pathout) throws Exception { 
    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJarByClass(ExerciseDriver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(ExerciseMapper2.class);
    job.setReducerClass(ExerciseReducer2.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);    
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,new Path(pathin));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(pathout));
    boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    return success ? 0 : -1;
}

   public int runThirdJob(String pathin, String pathout) throws Exception { 
    Job job = new Job(conf);
    job.setJarByClass(ExerciseDriver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(ExerciseMapper3.class);
    job.setReducerClass(ExerciseReducer3.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);    
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,new Path(pathin));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(pathout));
    boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
    return success ? 0 : -1;
}

  }
```

after just schedule the jar file in crontab. or else you can also go with oozie.as we mentioned in driver class the  3 mapreduce are executed one after other.first output is for second one input